# Security concerns of displaying ssh private key

Tags: bash, ssh, security, private-key

I've made a huge mistake, or at least I think I did: I've "catted" my private SSH key

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I'm now afraid that I've created a security hole, allowing other users to see my private key by looking at bash/scrollback history or using other methods.
So, my questions:

1. Did I really compromise the security of my SSH keypair?
2. Are there 'sufficiently secure' ways of patching it, excluding the
   obvious (and most secure) way of creating a new keypair?

(NOTE: i'm the only user of the machine so I'm actually not that concerned in my specific case, but I thought this would be an interesting question.)

Comment: user1686's answer is germane. But if you're worried about others gaining access to your private key in some way (roaming phones and you like to look at your key?), then put a passphrase on that private key and use ssh-agent. Google how to use ssh-agent. To put a passphrase on your key: `ssh-keygen -f path_to_key -p`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you did this in private, there's no problem. Think about it – you only displayed on screen the exact same data that is already stored on your harddisk anyway. And if anyone *could* access your scrollback or your history, they could just as well read the `id_rsa` file directly.

- Besides, your shell's history – even if it was readable to other users (which it isn't) – only contains commands, not their output. So all it'll have is a line with `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa` in it.
- The scrollback history, for most terminals, is stored entirely in memory. (libvte-based terminals sometimes use a backing file in /tmp, but that's either a *tmpfs* or is located in the same disk as your ~/.ssh, anyway...) So it becomes irrelevant once you close the terminal.
  And either way it is only accessible to you, of course.
- And very often, the private key itself is encrypted with a passphrase and is unusable unless you decrypt it when `ssh` asks to.

Unless, of course, you did this in the presence of high-resolution security cameras, or even outright allowed someone to snap a photo of your terminal window. In that case, someone could retype the key from photos, and the only thing protecting it would be the encryption passphrase.